# Missing input file with protoc in protocol buffer

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I currently have a file called addressbook.proto in next to my protoc.exe. I am having difficulty generating the .h and the .cc file. Here is what I am doing

```
protoc --cpp_out=c:\addressbook.proto
```

However I get the following response

```
Missing input file.
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: The -cpp_out tag specifies the output directory for generated c source code.

Comment: so what am I doig wrong ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The -cpp_out tag specifies the output directory for generated c source code.

I would suggest trying (if proto is actually stored under the c: directory c:\addressbook.proto)

```
protoc c:\addressbook.proto --cpp_out=./
```

or

```
protoc addressbook.proto --cpp_out=./
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the only answer in this thread didn't lead me to the solution I needed, here it is.

The syntax for calling the `protoc.exe` is as follows:

```
protoc --proto_path=<proto_directory> --cpp_out=<output_directory> <proto_file>
```

Important is that the argument to `proto_path` is a directory instead the specific `.proto`-file path. The actual proto files used are appended at the end of the command (`<proto_file>`).