# Proto file is not being recognised in command line?

Tags: protocols, protocol-buffers

Doing Google’s tutorial for Protocol Buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Trying to compile it into a java file using:

```
protoc -I=/home/Eggy/Desktop/Test/ --java_out=/home/Eggy/Desktop/Test/addressbook.proto
```

Error is: `Missing input file`

For some reason the file in the folder is unrecognised. If I press tab the file doesn't show in cmd.

Doing it this way: [Missing input file with protoc in protocol buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515840/missing-input-file-with-protoc-in-protocol-buffer) and this way https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/y2mxdn1vKGY

Brings up a different error:

```
File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I). You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).
```

I also created the file as a text file and saved it as a .proto if that helps in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is slightly off. The `--java_out` parameter needs to specify the *destination* folder, not the input file, and then you need a space before you list the input file.

Comment: Thanks, just figured out --java_out needs to specify destination directory and source directory!